# Could not coerce choice argument to boolean

Tags: jsp, el, conditional-operator

In my expression languange, I got an error of

> Could not coerce choice argument to   boolean

```
<a href="#" onclick="return openReplyBox(${comment.id});">
<span id="r_p" style="display: ${openReply ? 'none' : 'block'};">(+) <spring:message code="tab.reply"/></span>
<span id="r_m" style="display: ${openReply ? 'block' : 'none'};">(-)<spring:message code="tab.button.close" /></span>
```

Please let me know why is thing happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `openReply` variable is probably not of type `boolean`. Hence, you can't use it in a conditional ternary `? :` expression like that. If `openReply` contains a string like `true` or `false`, you can use the following expression:

```
<span id="r_p" style="display: ${openReply != 'true' ? 'none' : 'block'};">
```

Comment: is it safe to use == ? in String in EL?

Comment: You, and richersoon, please carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info to learn what "JSTL" actually is.

Comment: @richersoon Yes, it is completely safe i.e it matches the contents and not the string references. You can also use `eq`, `ne` which are aliases for `==`, `!=` in JSP EL.

Comment: @BalusC My bad, to say they were JSTL operators when it's pure EL and has nothing to do with the tags. I appreciate that you took time to correct the tags but honestly, sharing that link in my face, that hurt a bit :)